# How old should be my bitcoins to send them again without transaction fee?

Tags: bitcoind, transaction-fees, time

I'm making some test for a bitcoin merchant webpage. I want to test different actions without paying transaction fees everytime, but I can't since I use the same few bitcoins for everything.

Sooo how long should I wait for my bitcoins to be transfered wihout fee?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the coins "age" they will have a higher priority.

I don't know the algorithm, but believe it is roughly like a day or so and then the age of the coin no longer is a factor.

So if you are seeing minimum fees for coins more than a day after you've received them, it is because of other reasons, such as having outputs at amounts below 0.01 BTC.

Answer (score -2):

In the Bitcoin protocol, fees are totally optional.  You can have a fee of 0btc or 10btc.

Once there are more transactions then what fits into a block, which isn't now, miners will choose what transactions to include into their block, and they will prefer transactions with a fee attached, because they get that fee.

Right now, fees don't help process a transaction any sooner or better, but in the future it's likely to make a difference.  This totally depends on what happens in the future, and is very much up for debate.

Comment: Thanks Liquid5n0w. I think i didn't explain myself well, even if the transaction fees are optional right now, when you just receive bitcoins you can't re-send them inmediately without fee, bitcoind tells me to include a 0.005 fee because "i just received those bitcoins". I went and read about that, it seems to be that i have to wait for my bitcoins to be "old enough" to send them for free again.